# How to obtain the text contained in an element ID with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to be able to write a javascript function that returns the ID of a specific element as text to the screen without knowing the entire div id.  I will only know the first 6 characters of an id, and the last two characters will be two random numbers.

For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="coe02"></div>
<div id="bernar15"></div>
<div id="mason23"></div>
<div id="wolffe33"></div>
```

Lets say I wanted to return "bernar15"  how would I do that?

Right now I have :

```
var theDiv = $("div[id^='bernar']");
```

This returns the correct div, but now I want to obtain the entire id of that element.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: var theDiv = $("div[id^='bernar']").attr('id');
theDiv will now be "bernar15"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`theDiv.attr('id')` is what you need to return the full ID string

Comment: He wants the value of the "id" attribute, not the contents.

Comment: I just noticed that. My bad. Updated my original answer.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is...

```
var divID= $("div[id^='bernar']")[0].id;
```

It gets the div using jQuery, as you already had, but then gets the DOM element using `[0]`, and gets the id of it.

Comment: I think OP is after the ID of the element.

Comment: They just want the id, not the entire HTML defining the element.

Comment: @user2145333 No worries - glad to help.  Just be aware that that will only work as expected if your selector only returns 1 element.  If it returns more than 1 you'll get the 1st ID every time.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$("div[id^='bernar']").prop("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this jsfiddle

working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/fSuzz/2/)

```
var theDiv = $("div[id^=bernar]");

alert('id= ' +theDiv.attr('id'));
```